# How to execute pipeline at different times

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have requirement like . I have pipeline it contains 6 activities. I need to trigger the pipeline at 6 AM & 8 PM. At 6 AM I need to trigger the first 3 activities and next 3 activities I need to run at 8 PM.

Note: 6  activates in one pipeline.

Comment: Have you looked at the [If activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-if-condition-activity) in ADF?  You could use that and the Execute Pipeline activity.  Run the pipeline at the highest frequency and use conditions to control which parts of the pipeline execute at which times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What AbhishekKhandave-MT called out is accurate . In the worst case scneario you can always clone the existing pipeline and then you will have two pipeline , keep and choose activities what you want  and then schedule them accordingly .

In case you do not want to use the above suggestion , you can always use an IF actvity to check the time add the activites inside , I agree  it will be very messy that way .

Answer (score 1):

Trigger in Azure Data Factory are associated with Pipeline only. You can not run individual activities using trigger. Once you run pipeline, all activities in it will get executed.

Types of Trigger:

1. Schedule trigger
2. Tumbling window
3. Storage events
4. Custom events

Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory